# How do i align vertically in y axis an image just below of a custom TabBar of the parent view?

Tags: swiftui

I have a view (parent view) and I have the following ZStack View (child view) which contains an HStack. This HStack contains three other HStacks. I align the image to be on the center of the first HStack. My issue is that i need to move also the image vertically. The image needs to be moved at a certain y offset height based on the parent's view tabbar. The parent view consists of TabBar items that exist at a certain height. Please check image below.

Is it possible to get the y offset value of the tabbar that exists in the parent view and move the image with paddin below the y offset of the tabbar? Please check the image.

[image]

I know this might be an easy task to do but i am new to SwiftUI so any help appreciated.

```
//The code below shows the child view which is a ZStack that is shown above the tabbar view. The tabbar is custom and is shown at the top of the parent view

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        HStack {
            HStack {
                Image(.onboardingInstructionsArrowYellowUp)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(maxWidth: 24, maxHeight: 24)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        
            HStack {
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        
            HStack {
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take the time to cleanup your sample code indentation.
I'm not sure If I really understand what you are trying to do, but nesting your HStacks into VStacks and usign .offset might help.

Comment: Hello thanks for your suggestion i clean up my sample code. Let me explain. I have a view with a tab bar on top. This tabbar item is shown at a certain y offset at a certain height but i do not know what is the y offset is gonna be shown because of the different resolutions of the iPhones. So i need to find the y offset of the tabbar and show above it with a new view that has a zstack the image just below the tabbar. I have managed to create the view but i do not know how to show it just below the custom tabbar.

Comment: Could you also share the code of the custom tab bar and the parent view?
I'm still not sure if I got what you are trying to achieve.